# -fPIC を付けて再コンパイルしてください。. /usr/bin/ld: 最終リンクに失敗しました: 不正な値です. collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status. のエラー

Tags: python, python3

以下のようなエラーが出ました。
原因がわからないのですが、どのようにしたら解決するでしょうか。

よろしくお願い致します。

```
Python 3.6.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 13:06:04) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import keras
Using Theano backend.

You can find the C code in this temporary file: /tmp/theano_compilation_error_0rx2eexr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iota/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/lazylinker_c.py", line 81, in <module>
    actual_version, force_compile, _need_reload))
ImportError: Version check of the existing lazylinker compiled file. Looking for version 0.211, but found None. Extra debug information: force_compile=False, _need_reload=True

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iota/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/lazylinker_c.py", line 105, in <module>
    actual_version, force_compile, _need_reload))
ImportError: Version check of the existing lazylinker compiled file. Looking for version 0.211, but found None. Extra debug information: force_compile=False, _need_reload=True

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/iota/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import backend
  File "/home/iota/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from .theano_backend import *
  File "/home/iota/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
    import theano
  File "/home/iota/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    from theano.compile import (
  File "/home/iota/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/compile/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from theano.compile.mode import *
  File "/home/iota/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/compile/mode.py", line 11, in <module>
    import theano.gof.vm
  File "/home/iota/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/vm.py", line 674, in <module>
    from . import lazylinker_c
  File "/home/iota/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/lazylinker_c.py", line 140, in <module>
    preargs=args)
  File "/home/iota/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 2396, in compile_str
    (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): /usr/bin/ld: /home/iota/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/lib/libpython3.6m.a(ceval.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `_Py_NoneStruct' can not be used when making a shared object。 -fPIC を付けて再コンパイルしてください。. /usr/bin/ld: 最終リンクに失敗しました: 不正な値です. collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.
```

Comment: どの様な操作を行った結果、エラーが表示されたのかの詳しい手順等も質問文煮含めると回答する人のヒントになるかもしれません。 - 参考: [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

同様のエラーメッセージが出る例を見つけました（これはpyenv上のpysideですが）。

[Install pyside on Ubuntu 17.04 using pyenv : recompile with -fPIC · Issue #69 · pyside/pyside-setup](https://github.com/pyside/pyside-setup/issues/69)

そこで、[この問題を解決したコメント](https://github.com/pyside/pyside-setup/issues/69#issuecomment-300410987)を参考に、以下のようにpyenvを利用して `--enable-shared` フラグ付きでPythonをインストールしてみてください。

```
$ PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install 3.6.4
$ pyenv local 3.6.4
$ python3 -c 'import keras'
```